# Pachyphytum compactum small brown spots on leaves and large pale brown spot on stem

Tags: diseases, succulents

I've recently noticed that my pachyphytum compactum started to develop small brown spots on leaves and large pale brown spot on the stem has appeared.
It is very possibly that the succulent was overwatered for some time, but not much. Sunburns are also could be the reason, the pot was moved under artificial light source, however, other succulents look fine.

The question: do I need to cut healthy-looking leaves and replant, or something could be done? Thanks.
[image: Pale brown spot]
[image: Brown spots]